# iPhone: Error when using the FPPopover class when using it with a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using the [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover) class which creates popups for iPhones.
I followed the exact steps that are in the readme file but instead of using a UIbutton from a xib file, I am using a UIBarButtonItem created programmatically. But, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a3e420'

I copy pasted the same code as in the readme file but I just changed the (UIButton*)okButton with (id)sender  (id here is UIBarButtonItem*)

```
-(void)popover:(id)sender
{
    //the view controller you want to present as popover
    TestClass *controller = [[TestClass alloc] init];
    //our popover
    FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller];
    //the popover will be presented from the okButton view
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];
    //release
    [controller release];
}
```

I was thinking maybe it has to do with the UIBarButtonItem which is not a UIButton? Or is it anything else? I tried converting the UIBarButtonItem into UIButton but still gave me the same error. Any solutions to it?

One more note just in case: This is how I programmatically created the navigation bar along with the bar button:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 44)];
UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"By Clubs"];
[navBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:NO];
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter"
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                              target:self
                                              action:@selector(popover:)];


navItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

the presentPopoverFromView is only accepting a UIView subclass. UIBarButtonItem is not a subclass of UIView, so you need to find the view related to that button item. This is the solution I'm using with FPPopoverController

```
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = sender;
    UIView* btnView = [buttonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
    //On these cases is better to specify the arrow direction
    [popover setArrowDirection:FPPopoverArrowDirectionUp];
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:btnView];
```

This should work! Let me know!

Comment: this doesnt work for me... maybe i am not using it correctly. can u please add some more code to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's b/c [UIBarButtonItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inherits from `UIBarItem` and `NSObject`. Only UI elements that inherit from `UIView` have `superview` properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a solution to be able to click a button located in the upper right part of the sceen on the UINavigationBar and get a popup view upon clicking on it?

Comment: Try to put UIButton at the same place of rightBarButton item's place ie make the frame of UIButton same as of rightBarButton item try this out may solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. Solution is to create a UIButton Programatically (at the same place of UIBar button item - set the appropriate coordinates) and then present popover from UIButton. Then hide the UIButton.

This code worked for me:

```
-(void)testMethod {

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

// set action as NULL if you dont need any method/functionality to call

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(130, -40, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];

AlertsViewController *controller = [[AlertsViewController alloc] init]; 

//our popover
FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller]; 

//the popover will be presented from the Button view 
[popover presentPopoverFromView:button]; 

//hide the button
button.hidden = YES;

}

-(void)aMethod {
// Write any functionality if you need
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you get any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly applications display popover from BarButtonItem. FPPopOverController doesn't support this. So, in my opinion you should use: [WYPopOverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController)