# Application crashes when a method is called programmatically but works in IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ibaction

When I run this action from a button in IB the method is called fine. If I run it from code the app crashes with an **unrecognized selector sent to instance error**

here's the method:

```
-(void)bottomCenter:(id)sender
{
    [self popover:sender];
}

-(void)popover:(id)sender
{
    //the controller we want to present as a popover
    DemoTableController *controller = [[DemoTableController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    controller.delegate = self;
    popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller];

    //popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popover.tint = FPPopoverDefaultTint;

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 500);
    }
    else {
        popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 300);
    }

    popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionAny;

    //sender is the UIButton view
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];
}
```

and this is how I call it from a toolBar button:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *item3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icons-footer-filter.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(bottomCenter:)];
```

am I calling it incorrectly with `target:self action:@selector(bottomCenter:)` ?

Comment: Why don't you call the method popover directly? Whats the purpose of bottomSender?

Comment: call bottomCenter method without any argument. Remove the (id)sender stuff and then try

Comment: What is the uncrecognized selector? It should be telling you what you are trying to call that doesn't exist. Look at the error message more closely

Comment: It looks like it should work, is it crashing when you tap the button or when iOS attempts to add the button?

Comment: The problem may be elsewhere. Please show the code where you are adding the bar button item to the toolbar. I created a sample project doing what you said and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090536/388458)

The issue was due to UIBarButtonItem not a subclass of UIView...