# Function for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, selector

I'm using Core Data and I'm making a save button with this code:

```
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: Selector("saveTapped")), animated: true)
```

The save function:

```
  func saveTapped(){
            if (cell!.textField.text.isEmpty) {
                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Nevyplnené údaje"
                alert.message = "Musíš vyplniť všetky údaje o knihe."
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                alert.show()


            }
            let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let obsah: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: obsah)
            var pridat = Model(entity: entity! , insertIntoManagedObjectContext: obsah)

            pridat.kniha = cell!.textField.text
            pridat.autor = cell!.textField.text
            pridat.rok = cell!.textField.text
            pridat.vydavatelstvo = cell!.textField.text
            pridat.strany = cell!.textField.text

            obsah.save(nil)
        }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> 2015-04-29 19:12:42.762 iKnižnica[25716:11689183]
>   -[iKniz_nica.PridatViewController saveTapped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff5ab63ff50 2015-04-29 19:12:42.851
>   iKnižnica[25716:11689183] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[iKniz_nica.PridatViewController saveTapped]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x7ff5ab63ff50'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100bccc65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000102737bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000100bd40ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b2a13c
>   ___forwarding_** + 988    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b29cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   UIKit
>   0x000000010146cda2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>     6   UIKit                               0x000000010146cda2
>   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75    7   UIKit                               0x000000010157e54a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
>     8   UIKit                               0x000000010157d919
>   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522    9   UIKit                               0x00000001014b9998 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735  10  UIKit 
>   0x00000001014ba2c2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682   11  UIKit
>   0x0000000101480581 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246  12  UIKit
>   0x000000010148dd1c _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265    13
>   UIKit                               0x00000001014685dc
>   _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066     14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b00431
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100af62fd
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269   16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100af5934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868     17  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000100af5366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     18  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000104bb3a3e GSEventRunModal + 161  19  UIKit
>   0x000000010146b900 UIApplicationMain + 1282   20  iKnizÃånica
>   0x00000001005c6377 main + 135     21  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000102e8f145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

I posted the source code here: http://pastebin.com/M9AMakGr

Comment: Try change `Selector("saveTapped")` to `Selector("saveTapped:")`

Comment: tried... Same problem

Comment: @dafinaoo read [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098991/how-to-add-action-to-a-barbuttonitem-in-a-navcontroller-that-was-created-program). `Maybe Selector(saveTapped:)`

Comment: In Swift u can't use Selector(saveTapped:) without "

Comment: ohhh.. Just use only "saveTapped:" [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Comment: send me your project dr_temka@icloud.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not in the button settings, but in function

Instead of:

```
func saveTapped(){
```

Should be:

```
func saveTapped(sender:UIButton){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your setRightBarButtonItem code to below code:

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "saveTapped:"), animated: true)
```

In swift, for selector you just need to type the name of the function, that's it! Hope it helps

Comment: @dafinoo What's wrong in it? Can you please specify?

Comment: Put it in xcode u will see.. bad brackets and if u put it how it should be u will get my code :) Try it :)

Comment: @dafinoo Really sorry for that! See the edited code, it will definitely works. Let me know your problem if appears!

Comment: @dafinoo So what error you are getting? Get screenshot of that too please

Comment: http://screenshot.cz/MUFNQ/hmm.png u also got source code http://pastebin.com/M9AMakGr