# Get the indexpath from a UIBarButtonItem in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UITableViewController` like this. A grouped table view with a `UIBarButtonItem` in the accessoryView of each row.

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[TransparentToolbar alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *loginButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                   target:self
                                                                   action:@selector(login:)];
    toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 103);
    toolBar.items = @[loginButton];
    cell.accessoryView = toolBar;

    return cell;
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the indexpath of the `UITableViewCell` when clicked upon the corresponding `UIBarButtonItem`. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090536/1077789))

```
- (void)login:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
{
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = button;
    UIView *view = [barButton valueForKey:@"view"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"secton: %d", indexPath.section);
}
```

But it only returns 0 no matter which bar button I click. Anyone can tell me what's wrong with it and how to correct this? I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: YOu can add a `tag` to the barButton in `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then get that `tag` value in the `login` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `view.superview.superview;` instead of `view.superview;`

Comment: Wow! this worked! This is a much more elegant way. Could you please explain how this line - `view.superview.superview;` works in my case? Thanks for the answer btw. :)

Comment: I cannot test it at this moment, but I think view.superview is accesoryView of the cell in this case. Cell is superview of it.

Answer (score 2):

you set loginutton tag like this way

```
loginButton.tag=indexPath.section;
```

get indexpath in click event

```
- (void)login:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
{
UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:button.tag];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[loginButton setTag:indexPath.section];
```

Login:

```
   NSLog(@"secton: %d",(long int) [barButton tag]);
```

Answer (score 1):

CellForRow:--

```
loginButton.tag=indexPath.row;
```

Login Action Method:--

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:button.tag inSection:0];
```

Answer (score -1):

set the different tag for each barbutton item in each cell.then according to the button tag you can find which cell it is.you can access like this

```
UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```